# Rails remote form sends html instead of js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a remote `form_for` in my Rails 4 app that is not requesting a JavaScript response. I am getting an UnknownFormat error when I click submit on the form. It is saying the parameters were:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"eAzS1lELwDL9Qt+fM2hAPlPmCxCgFPuAvl1QYWOIL3IBPdrnxn0woYYC+5uzGjyqH3lQxGxWGrYq/fnMrFNfnw==",
 "artist"=>{"name"=>"Joe"},
 "commit"=>"Save Artist"}
```

My form code is:

```
= form_for(@artist, remote: true, authenticity_token: true) do |f|
  - if @artist.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@artist.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this artist from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @artist.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save Artist'
```

I have a `create.js.erb` file, and my `create` method in my `ArtistsController` looks like:

```
  def new
    @artist = Artist.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @artist = Artist.new(artist_params)

    if @artist.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

My shows form is:

```
= form_for @show, html: {role: 'form'} do |f|
  - if @show.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@show.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this venue from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @show.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .row
    = f.label :venue_id
    = f.collection_select :venue_id, Venue.all, :id, :name, class: 'form-control'
  .row
    .col-sm-6
      = link_to 'New Artist', new_artist_path, id: :new_artist_link, remote: true
  .row.row-centered
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :date
        = f.date_select :show_date, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :doors_open
        = f.time_select :doors_open, class: 'form-control'
  .row.row-centered
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :dinner_starts
        = f.time_select :dinner_starts, class: 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :show_starts
        = f.time_select :show_starts, class: 'form-control'
  .row.row-centered
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :dinner_ends
        = f.time_select :dinner_ends, class: 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :show_ends
        = f.time_select :show_ends, class: 'form-control'

  .form-group
    = f.submit 'Save Show', class: 'btn btn-default'
```

My `new.js.erb` file in my artists view is:

```
$('#new_artist_link').hide().after("<%= j render 'form' %>");
```

And my `create.js.erb` that is in my artists view is:

```
$('#new_artist').remove();
```

Console output:

```
tarted GET "/artists/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-26 22:46:12 -0600
Processing by ArtistsController#new as JS
  Rendered artists/_form.html.haml (2.7ms)
  Rendered artists/new.js.erb (4.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 8.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started POST "/artists" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-26 22:46:16 -0600
Processing by ArtistsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0dhmOLTBguCAn4gdaIE0D0PyokHp4RLLZ8DDeqiA21Wo6W4JI7dyc/vfrBno80ibD235lSWj8/3zYGrXZ1uruA==", "artist"=>{"name"=>"fsa"}, "commit"=>"Save Artist"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "artists" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "fsa"], ["created_at", "2015-02-27 04:46:16.795869"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-27 04:46:16.795869"]]
   (209.8ms)  commit transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 213ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/artists_controller.rb:20:in `create'


  Rendered /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@DoseyDoe/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@DoseyDoe/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@DoseyDoe/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@DoseyDoe/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@DoseyDoe/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (26.7ms)
```

EDIT: I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but the remote form is in the form for another model.

EDIT 2: Fixed create method - still no dice. Added the form template that I am using that links to creating the artist.

EDIT 3: Added console output

EDIT 4: Added `create.js.erb`

Comment: Your create method does not actually create the record. It only initializes. Fix it and see if it works. You need a @artist.save or change Artist.new to Artist.create

Comment: @Mingsheng Still no dice. I updated the original post with the new code and added some more code - maybe that will help.

Comment: Web server console output please! That's the first place to look to find out what your app thinks you are asking for and what it's telling you. Also it helps to see the actual relevant chunk of the HTML from the generated page.

Comment: Can you check if the form is requesting javascript? that might be why your controller is confused since there's only format.js. It seems like you are requesting html here

Comment: @Mingsheng How do I check that? I was under the impression adding remote: true made it request JavaScript.

Comment: "Processing by ArtistsController#create as HTML"
This line suggests that it is requesting html. maybe you can start by adding ".js" to the submit path. You can try adding url: _italic_path_italic_(@artist, format: :js) to the form

Comment: @Mingsheng How do I do that?

Comment: wait... there's an easier way. You can just add format: :js http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: @Mingsheng Lol thanks. That kind of fixed it. But created a new problem that I mentioned in the comment to thedeeno's answer below.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out the issue? I am having the same problem. Only difference is I turned off turbolinks. Thats about it. But it also prints out the javascript on the page when adding the format param to JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the `format` param to the `form_for`. You're requesting an `html` response by default and your controller doesn't know how to answer that. Requesting a `js` response should fix it.

```
= form_for(@artist, format: :js, authenticity_token: true) do |f|
```

Comment: Okay, that worked but now it is just displaying the JavaScript in my response. My create.js.erb file should remove the form that was used to create the new artist. All that happens is that it replaces everything that was on the page with the jQuery text that was in my create.js.erb file.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I thought that remote: true made it request a js response? What's the point of remote: true then?

Comment: @ThomYorkkke it should, but that requires the rails javascript utilities to be loaded (and they might not be in this case). Make sure the `jquery_ujs` library (or today's equivalent) is included.

Comment: I've made sure I have the jquery_ujs and jquery, but I'm still just getting text instead of having my jQuery running. I have other jQuery in the site that is running fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your `create.js.erb` file posted in the question? I don't see it.

Comment: I just added it, it's under my new.js.erb - I haven't fully written that part yet, but I have tried replacing what I have in there with other valid JavaScript and nothing will execute. It just keeps getting printed as text.

Comment: It could be that your JS is crashing or being malformed in some way. If you're including the layout in the response that will break the JS parser. Try adding `format.js {render layout: false}`. For another method checkout this blog post: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/

Comment: Hmm yeah, I tried those, no success. Firebug wasn't even picking up any jQuery code to give me warnings about. This is very weird.

Comment: @ThomYorkkke what's the generated html code for the form?

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered same error and after few hours of debugging found out, that `rails ujs` was required, but not loaded properly.
If you're using `webpack`, make sure to `start` `ujs`. In my case I forgot the `start();` option, i.e.

```
import Rails from '@rails/ujs'; 
Rails.start();
```

or

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
```

if you prefer the `require` syntax.

Comment: I have the latter in my /app/javascript/packs/application.js but I still receive a html render in return. My call is type = xhr and initiated from rails-ujs. Any tipps?

Comment: You probably already tried setting `format: :js` in the form, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found my problem. In rails 6 the layout will also applied to js-files, unless you name it layout.html.erb